# difficulty pushing data to an array during async request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the following code, I'm wondering why my console.log(dataArray) displays an empty array. I think the console.log may be called before the ajax request is finished pulling data. If this is the case, is there any way to wait for the ajax request to finish before calling console.log ?

```
var dataArray = [];

var gdpAPI = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";
  $.getJSON( gdpAPI, {
    format: "json",
    async: false

  })
    .done(function( data ) {


    yearsData = data['data']


    $.each(yearsData, function(i){
       dataArray.push(yearsData[i]);


    })


 });

 console.log(dataArray);
```

Thank you in advance.
Wyatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Async Code

You're right that the `console.log` was called before the request finished. Just put your log statement inside of the `.done` section and it will work.

### [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/453ef5c7/1/)

```js
var dataArray = [];

var gdpAPI = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";
$.getJSON(gdpAPI, {
    format: "json",
    async: false

  })
  .done(function(data) {


    yearsData = data['data']

    $.each(yearsData, function(i) {
      dataArray.push(yearsData[i]);


    })
  console.log('length: ' + dataArray.length,dataArray);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Simple and accurate explanation, I'll have to keep this in mind. Thanks adriancarriger

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a callback function to get the data out of the function and manipulate the data where sendMethedata is your callback function

```js
var dataArray = [];

var gdpAPI = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";
  $.getJSON( gdpAPI, {
    format: "json",
    async: true

  })
    .done(function( data ) {


   var yearsData = data['data']


    $.each(yearsData, function(i){
       dataArray.push(yearsData[i]);


    });
    sendMethedata(dataArray);

 });

function sendMethedata(data){
console.log(data)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```